# How do I make it responsive?

Tags: css, image, responsive

I bought this template and I'm editing. It uses bootstrap but this image seems to be with some problem and it changes the size in different monitors. I tried to add:

```
.responsive {width: auto; height: auto;}
```

to fix it but I didn't get any result. What else can I do?
PS. I'll attach a copy of the HTML/CSS I'm using.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 right-side order-1 order-lg-2">
  <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade active show responsivo" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
       <img src="images/macbook_1.png" alt="Equipe Quest Group" class="container_resp">
    </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade **responsive**" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">
    <img src="images/macbook_2.png" alt="Quest Logo" class="container_resp">
  </div>
 </div>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxyXw.png)

Comment: All those `col-lg-6 right-side order-1 order-lg-2` suggest the site is using a possibly responsive CSS framework.

Answer (score 0):

make image responsive by adding css

```
img{
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```